# Stuck at compaction

Tags: cassandra

I'm having a strange issue with the automatic compaction of Cassandra. I'm using cassandra 3.7 on a Debian 8 system, and after pushing about 70GB of data to a cassandra node (it's a single node with RF=1 for testing purposes), running a ***nodetool compactionstats*** from the command line I get:

```
root@cassandra01:~# nodetool compactionstats
pending tasks: 280
- system.batches: 280
```

and no other information are displayed. Checking the ***system.log***
 I get:

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:74] 2016-08-23 19:41:30,006 CassandraDaemon.java:217 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:74,1,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata$Chunk.<init>(CompressionMetadata.java:475) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.chunkFor(CompressionMetadata.java:240) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.MmappedRegions.updateState(MmappedRegions.java:158) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.MmappedRegions.<init>(MmappedRegions.java:73) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.MmappedRegions.<init>(MmappedRegions.java:61) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.MmappedRegions.map(MmappedRegions.java:99) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedSegmentedFile.<init>(CompressedSegmentedFile.java:44) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedSegmentedFile$Builder.complete(CompressedSegmentedFile.java:135) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Builder.complete(SegmentedFile.java:181) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Builder.buildData(SegmentedFile.java:192) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.openEarly(BigTableWriter.java:271) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.maybeReopenEarly(SSTableRewriter.java:182) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.append(SSTableRewriter.java:134) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.DefaultCompactionWriter.realAppend(DefaultCompactionWriter.java:65) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.append(CompactionAwareWriter.java:141) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:187) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:60) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:264) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2016-08-23 19:42:05,511 Ref.java:203 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@57d68945) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Cleanup@831676520:/cassandra/disk1/system/batches-919a4bc57a333573b03e13fc3f68b465/mb-44056-big-Index.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2016-08-23 19:42:05,511 Ref.java:203 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@39229a12) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@1862266673:Memory@[7fb261a66020..7fb261a69220) was not released before the reference was garbage collected
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2016-08-23 19:42:05,511 Ref.java:203 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@d80df0a) to class org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.WrappedSharedCloseable$Tidy@791904242:[Memory@[0..188), Memory@[0..f50)] was not released before the reference was garbage collected
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2016-08-23 19:42:05,523 Ref.java:203 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@26c920c) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.MmappedRegions$Tidier@326857495:/cassandra/disk1/system/batches-919a4bc57a333573b03e13fc3f68b465/mb-44056-big-Data.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
```

It seems to me that cassandra hangs somewhere in the `CompressionMetadata` class and gets an exception, and then after a bit the ***Reference-Reaper*** finds a memory leak due to the uncaught exception. The problem, however, never goes away, as these errors keep showing in the log every 30 seconds or so.

Has anyone ever see that thing before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen that error before, but it sounds like perhaps you pushed the data to the single node too fast. It might seem like it was able to handle the write load, but probably after a while it was not able to keep up with the compactions and kept creating more compaction jobs until something overflowed. Possibly you now have some corrupted SSTables.

Try pushing the data at a slower rate and monitor compactionstats during the push to make sure compaction jobs are able to finish in a timely fashion and not accumulating. If you can't slow down the write rate, then you may need more nodes to split the load.

The closest error I've seen to that is after pushing a lot of data there were several queued compaction jobs shown in compactionstats, but none of them would start and they just sat there. I was able to clear that by doing a rolling restart of all the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks Jim,during writes I saw compactions of ordinary tables created and completed successfully.I also saw `system.batches` compactions,but they usually completed.After stressing the system a while these `system.batches` started to accumulate(others tables too).When the node was idle the others compactions completed,but these 280 did not.I had to wipe the node and push the data again.If I push the data at slower rate everything is fine,however I usually pause writing when I get a timeout(eg the node is under pressure),so I write always at "max" speed.